# Local url to external url in a HTML5 web banner

Tags: html, banner

A website that I want to run advertising on has asked me to send them the index file for a HTML5 banner, they want all files linked in the index to be hosted on my domain.

I can't figure out how to change the local path of the image to a external path. Here's the code in my index file that references the image in the banner:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="ad.size" content="width=300,height=50">
        
        <title></title>
        <style>:root{--retina-src:''}html{box-sizing:border-box;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;text-rendering:optimizeLegibility}body,html{background:transparent;line-height:1.4;margin:0;padding:0}*{box-sizing:border-box}#bs{overflow:hidden}#bs .bs-helper{height:100%;left:0;top:0;width:100%;z-index:-1}.background{background:50% 50% no-repeat;background-size:cover}.background-stretch{background-size:100% 100%}.background-crop{background:no-repeat 50% 50%;background-size:cover}
.background-mask{background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:auto auto}.background-aspect{background:no-repeat 50% 50%;background-size:contain}.background-tile{background-repeat:repeat}.slide{height:100%;left:0;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:0;transition:none;width:100%;-webkit-perspective-origin:center;perspective-origin:center}.slide>.slide-hover{display:none;height:100%;left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%}.slide.buildin>.slide-hover,.slide.buildout>.slide-hover{display:block}.element{position:absolute;perspective-origin:center;-webkit-perspective-origin:center}
.element>.eff-helper{transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none){.element{transform-style:preserve-3d;-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d}.element>.eff-helper{transform:none;-webkit-transform:none}}@supports(-ms-ime-align:auto){.element{-webkit-transform-style:flat;transform-style:flat}}.element .text,.countdown{line-height:1.4;margin:0;white-space:pre-line;word-break:normal;word-wrap:break-word;font-variant-ligatures:none}.element .text.boundary{word-wrap:normal}
.element .shape{height:100%;width:100%}.element .shape.circle{border-radius:50%}.element .embed{height:100%;overflow:hidden;width:100%}.element .svg,.element .svg img{width:100%;height:100%;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;transform:perspective(1px)}.element .menu{-webkit-align-content:center;align-content:center;-webkit-flex-wrap:nowrap;flex-wrap:nowrap;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;display:flex}
.element .menu label{cursor:pointer;display:inline-block;flex:1 1 auto;text-align:center;-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none}.element .menu label span{display:inline-block;position:relative;white-space:nowrap}.element .menu.ie9{display:table;table-layout:auto}.element .menu.ie9 label{display:table-cell;padding:0 5px}.bs-btn{-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;overflow:hidden;border-radius:.01px}
.bs-btn label{cursor:pointer;float:left;margin:0;position:relative;text-align:center;width:100%;top:50%;transform:translateY(-50%);white-space:nowrap}.bs-btn.no-hand-cursor label,.bs-btn.no-hand-cursor div{cursor:default}.bs-image{height:100%;width:100%}.bs-clipart,.bs-clipart-blur{height:100%;position:relative;width:100%}.bs-clipart svg{position:absolute}.image-stretch{background-size:100% 100%}.image-crop{background:no-repeat 50% 50%;background-size:cover}.image-mask{background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:auto auto}
.image-aspect{background:no-repeat 50% 50%;background-size:contain}.image-tile{background-repeat:repeat}.eff-helper{width:100%;height:100%}.action-container{width:100%;height:100%;display:block;text-decoration:none}.bs-video{-o-object-fit:cover;object-fit:cover;-o-object-position:center;object-position:center;outline:0}.hide-media-controls::-webkit-media-controls{display:none}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2),only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:2),only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio:2/1),only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio:2),only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi),only screen and (min-resolution:2dppx){.retina{background-image:var(--retina-src) !important}
}</style>
                                  
        <script src="db87f55674e4449c9698e18e55d490cd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.bsOpenURL = function (url, target) {        if (url && url.length > 0) {            window.open(url, target);        }    }
            
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
            window.mediaPlayTimeout = [];
            window.goToURLWithoutBSURL = false;
            window.bannerURL = "";
            window.bannerConfig = {"startSlide":0,"noAnimation":false,"preview":false,"printScreen":false,"showOnlyOneSlide":false,"video":false,"download":true,"showWatermark":false,"networkId":1,"env":"live","watermark":{"show":false},"fontLocalPath":"fonts/","imgLocalPath":"media/"};
            window.bannerJson = {"banner":{"properties":{"width":300,"height":50,"loop":false,"loopCount":1,"bannerUrl":"","urlTarget":"_blank","useHandCursor":false,"backgroundColor":{"borderColor":"#3d3d3d","scolor":"#fdc944","type":"solid","gradColors":null,"rgradPos":null,"backgroundRotation":null,"contentScale":100,"scaleMode":"crop","useBorder":false,"horizontalAlign":"center","verticalAlign":"middle","contentOffsetX":50,"contentOffsetY":50,"originalWidth":0,"originalHeight":0,"url":null,"hqUrl":null,"source":null,"hash":null,"licensing":false},"useAsClickTag":false,"retina":false,"fallbackImage":false},"elements":[{"properties":{"duration":7,"id":8,"bannersetElementId":1,"stopSlide":false,"guidelines":{"v":[],"h":[]}},"type":"slide","elements":[{"type":"layer","layerType":"text","properties":{"id":30,"bannersetElementId":4,"elementCategory":null,"opacity":100,"rotation":0,"x":123,"y":6,"width":206.53956239389905,"height":45,"buildIn":{"type":"instant","delay":1,"duration":1},"actions":[],"locked":false,"lockedProperties":[],"visible":true,"group":null,"mediaFolderId":null,"originalName":null,"openAdvancedProperties":false,"alignment":"left","fontSize":25,"lineHeight":0.9,"letterSpacing":1,"config":{"type":"slate","nodes":[{"type":"paragraph","defaultFontSettings":{"fontFamily":"Playfair Display SC","fontType":"google","fontWeight":700,"fontStyle":"normal","fontUrl":null,"fontFaceUrl":null},"children":[{"text":"Luxury hotel rooms","color":"#005c37","textScript":"none","textDecoration":"none","textTransform":"none","fontSettings":{"fontFamily":"Playfair Display SC","fontType":"google","fontWeight":700,"fontStyle":"normal","fontUrl":null,"fontFaceUrl":null}}]}],"selection":null},"initialFontSize":25,"textDirection":null,"scale":0.8228621785218196,"blendMode":"normal","outline":{"useOutline":false,"color":"","weight":null}}},{"type":"layer","layerType":"image","properties":{"id":31,"bannersetElementId":5,"elementCategory":null,"opacity":100,"rotation":0,"x":0,"y":0,"width":110,"height":50,"actions":[],"locked":false,"lockedProperties":[],"visible":true,"group":null,"mediaFolderId":null,"originalName":null,"openAdvancedProperties":false,"url":"00803","scaleMode":"crop","horizontalAlign":"center","verticalAlign":"middle","adjustColor":{"useAdjustColor":true,"brightness":2,"contrast":-7,"saturate":13,"hue":0},"contentScale":100,"contentOffsetX":50,"contentOffsetY":50,"originalWidth":640,"originalHeight":426,"hqUrl":null,"cropData":null,"maskImage":null,"source":null,"hash":"","licensing":false,"blendMode":"normal","localUrl":"76dea57b8c673d3c8ea31cb4f0124804.jpg","backupUrl":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"}},{"type":"layer","layerType":"svg","properties":{"id":32,"bannersetElementId":6,"elementCategory":null,"opacity":100,"rotation":0,"x":9,"y":4,"width":28,"height":42,"actions":[],"locked":false,"lockedProperties":[],"visible":true,"group":null,"mediaFolderId":null,"originalName":null,"openAdvancedProperties":false,"url":"mz9k71","colorGroups":{"0":"#FDC944","1":"#333333"},"originalWidth":100,"originalHeight":149,"resourceKey":null,"lineData":null,"source":null,"localUrl":"613c8a7f98954c36c68151cf4d1fc01f.svg"}}]}],"resources":{}},"hash":"ek5y88w","userId":836689};
            window.urlTarget = "_blank";
        </script>    
    </head>
    <body><div id="bs"></div></body>
</html>
```

The code that references the image URL is here:

```
"localUrl":"76dea57b8c673d3c8ea31cb4f0124804.jpg"
```

Notes:

- I don't know what programming language this is.
- This code was exported from Creatopy - a website that creates HTML5 banners without needing to know coding.

How do I change the image link from a local URL to an external URL?

I've tried uploading all the files to my domain and changing the code as shown below but it doesn't work. E.g.

Changing:

`"localUrl":"76dea57b8c673d3c8ea31cb4f0124804.jpg"`

to

`"Url":"https://www.example.com/media/76dea57b8c673d3c8ea31cb4f0124804.jpg"`

This doesn't work and the image is broken when I open the index file.

Here's a preview of an example web banner: https://app.creatopy.com/share/d/2q72eox55j7o

All the code is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AOSmLzbrp1V-xG5iIxzKP-Uo00MTcMED/view?usp=share_link

Comment: It looks like you should hire a developer to fix code you earn money with...? The fix is probably rather simple (have you checked the browser console for errors? Does your webspace allow hotlinking images?). This seems like minimized code. You should ask if you can get hands on of the original source, maybe that has some knobs to supply the external URL or similar.

Comment: Thanks Peter. yes, I'll be hiring a developer if I can't find a solution I just thought it might be a really easy fix.

I've checked the browse console for errors, it's still trying to get the image from the local url instead of the external url.

I don't think changing "localUrl" to "Url" is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Well it seems like already somewhat minified code, that's always a stretch to find the right way. You can try keeping "localUrl" but putting the full URL in its value. "url" is already taken with some other value.

Comment: I have the exact same problem - did the same thing as you, but with lowercase "url"